# CakePHP 2.0 database connection issue

Tags: cakephp

I'm using a standard MySQL db on my server and trying to connect my install of CakePHP 2.0 to it. I'm using this for my settings:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',
    'login' => 'mylogin',
    'password' => 'mypw',
    'database' => 'mydb',   
);
```

But my cakephp page comes up as cannot connect to the database. I've set debug to 2, but how do I find out what is the issue with the database connection?

I've also tried a normal mysql connect in a .ctp file and it works fine with the login/password I give it...

Comment: Dont you just need a host? And check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212290/cake-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-database

Comment: with 2.0, it says if I specify unix_socket there is no need for host/port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you dont not have the PDO_Mysql extension enabled, as thats what CakePHP 2.0 uses.

Try to create a small script outside of CakePHP, to see if this is enabled. And try to connect to the database with:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php